EAS Build Failing with "Undefined Symbols for Architecture arm64" Error in React Native Project
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
┌─ Symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTEventDispatcher
└─ Referenced from: __OBJC_$_CATEGORY_RCTEventDispatcher_$_Reanimated in RCTEventDispatcher+Reanimated.o
❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I am encountering a build error when running eas build --platform ios for my React Native project using Expo on VSCode. The build stops at line 3068 with the following error:
The error seems to involve the RCTEventDispatcher symbol from the react-native-reanimated library. Here are some details about my setup:

React Native version: 0.74.1

Stripe version: 0.37.2

react-native-reanimated version: 3.10.1

Build tool: EAS

Development environment: VSCode with Expo


I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Deleted node_modules and yarn.lock, then reinstalled dependencies with yarn install.

Ran pod install --repo-update in the ios directory.

Verified build settings in the eas.json file to ensure correct architecture settings.


Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this linker error when using Expo and VSCode? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my Podfile:
platform :ios, '14.0'

require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

use_modular_headers!

prepare_react_native_project!

target 'SP' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] != 'false',
  )

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'react-native-reanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 23.26.0'
  pod 'StripePaymentsUI', '~> 23.26.0'
  pod 'StripeApplePay', '~> 23.26.0'
  pod 'StripeFinancialConnections', '~> 23.26.0'
  pod 'StripePaymentSheet', '~> 23.26.0'

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      :ccache_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.ccacheEnabled'] == 'true',
    )

    installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
      .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
      target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
        resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'react-native-reanimated'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['USE_HERMES'] = 'YES'
        end
      end
    end

    # Exclude arm64 for simulator builds
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
    end

    # Ensure Hermes dependencies
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'hermes-engine'
        target.add_dependency target
      end
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end


Any update on this?
